# using a model saved in keras in spark

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, pyspark, keras, pickle

I have to broadcast a model that has been saved using

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Broadcasting the model as

```
sc.broadcast((load_model('my_model.h5'))
```

throws the following error:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize broadcast: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

I have tried saving the json format of model as well but no luck there too. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of python, pyspark and keras are you using?

Comment: python - 2.7.6, spark - 2.1.1, keras - 2.0.5